# Select rows based on duplicates in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find all duplicates in a column and display the primary key so I can clean them up.

So after a bunch of tutorials I have this which is supposed to work and returns no rows which is great because it means there's nothing I need to clean up. 'equipment_id' is the primary key on the table

```
SELECT
    equipment_id, tent_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    equipment
GROUP BY
    equipment_id, tent_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But when I just look for the dupes like this without involving the primary key column

```
SELECT
    tent_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    equipment
GROUP BY
    tent_id
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

I get 900+ results, which is also fine but I need the primary key so I know which ones to edit.

```
TABLE equipment

ROWS
equipment_id    tent type    tent_id    note
100             large        66666      out
101             small        66666      in
102             small        55555      in
103             large        44444      in
104             small        33333      out
```

The result I want will look like

```
100      66666
101      66666
```

Comment: I don't completely follow/understand your question.  Can you add sample data which helps to explain what you are asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first query be returning any records *and* the `equipment_id` really be a primary key column, then it must be the case that a single `tent_id` value is associated with multiple records/multiple `equipment_id` values.  To find this `tent_id` values, try asserting the distinct count of the `equipment_id`:

```
SELECT tent_id
FROM equipment
GROUP BY tent_id
HAVING COUNT(equipment_id) > 1;
```

To generate the output you want, you could try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT equipment_id, tent_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tent_id) cnt
    FROM equipment
)

SELECT
    equipment_id,
    tent_id
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need distinct `equipment_id` vs. grouped `tent_id`

```
SELECT *
  FROM equipment
 WHERE tent_id IN
  (      
   SELECT tent_id
     FROM equipment
    GROUP BY tent_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT equipment_id) > 1
  );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a587ddfa45867c4975a253d1df44c938)</kbd>